# Pasar de Resources<List<Games>> a List<Games>

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

estoy empezando a trabajar con Kotlin y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo agrego en imagen para que se vea que it es un Resource<List< Games>>

Mi duda es como pasar de este "it" a un List< Games> para poder ponerlo en las XXXXX del adapter del Recycler

Answer (score 1):

```
val list: List<Games>? = null
list = it as List<Games>?
```

Comment: Tu respuesta carece de formato y de explicaciones, por tal motivo puede terminar eliminada o movida a un comentario - [desde revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/253411)